# How to search a multi-line pattern in a text and get the last occurrence?

Tags: linux, command-line, awk

I need to find pgp encrypted messages in a file. They begin with `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----` and end with `-----END PGP MESSAGE-----`.

So far I have this:

```
$ tail -200 somefile | awk '/-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----/,/-----END PGP MESSAGE-----/'
```

It's finding all the occurrences, but I only want the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sed:

```
tail -200 somefile | sed -n '
  # only consider lines between BEGIN and END
  /-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----/,/-----END PGP MESSAGE-----/ {
    # if the beginning line, clear the hold space
    /-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----/{x;d}
    # add the line to the hold space
    H
  };
  # print the hold space at the end
  ${x;p}'
```

This sed comment (the comments are for explanation and are not needed in the actual command), any lines between "BEGIN" and "END" will be added to the hold space, with the hold space being cleared on every "BEGIN" and then printed at the end.

EDIT:

For completeness here is the version without comments and on a single line (does the same as above)

```
tail -200 somefile | sed -n '/-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----/,/-----END PGP MESSAGE-----/{/-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----/{x;d};H};${x;p}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
/-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----/ {
    inBlock = 1
    block = ""
}
inBlock {
    block = block $0 ORS
    if (/-----END PGP MESSAGE-----/) {
        inBlock = 0
    }
}
END {
    printf "%s", block
}
' somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN {
    beginmsg = "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----"
    endmsg = "-----END PGP MESSAGE-----"
}

$0 ~ beginmsg {
    block = ""
}

beginmsg,endmsg {
    block = block $0 ORS
}

END {
    printf "%s", block
}
```